# swift. переписать код на Swift 5.2

Tags: swift

Как будет выглядеть этот  код на Swift 5.2? Спасибо.

```
  enum Rank{
    case ace
    case face(String)
    case numeric(Int)
    var order:Int{
        switch self{
        case .ace:return 1
        case .numeric(let pips):return pips
        case .face(let kind) where kind =="J":return 11
        case .face(let kind) where kind =="Q":return 12
        case .face(let kind) where kind =="K":return 13
        default: return 0
            
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Помойму также...

Comment: Добавил скрин с ошибками и изменил немного код

Comment: Просто пробел после `==` поставьте... `kind == "J"` итд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
enum Rank {
    case ace
    case face(String)
    case numeric(Int)
    var order: Int {
        switch self {
        case .ace: return 1
        case .numeric(let pips): return pips
        case .face(let kind):
            switch kind {
            case "J": return 11
            case "Q": return 12
            case "K": return 13
            default: return 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```